# Can't get Guzzle to force content-type for raw image data

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 6 and having a problem getting image data back from a REST endpoint.

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => $base_uri]);
$type = 'POST';  //..or 'GET'...doesn't make a difference
$url = //..the endpoint where the image is served from
$headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=x-user-defined';
$response = $client->request($type, $url, ['headers'=>$headers, 'decode_content' => false] );
```

My request to force the mime type is being ignored and the returned content-type is always `"image/jpeg"`, and the data is munged so I can't simply stick it into an html `"<img src=... />"` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force the content-type of the **response**.

The `Content-Type` header you use is the content-type for the **request** and not the **response**.

If the endpoint (API?) you use gives you the ability to control the response, it will probably will be based on the URL you are using, but it is not something you can just tell Guzzle to change.

Comment: thanks...I finally realized that I could do whatever I want with the data from the stream that comes back; in this case if I encode it to base64 and put the correct hint in front of it:  `data:image/jpeg;base64,` -- the html `<img>` tag works fine.